# 'TwitterException' with message 'Not Found'

Tags: social-network

Viewing the syslog, I see errors like for the Twitter Module 7.x-5.11

Do you have an idea of how to solve it?

'TwitterException' with message 'Not Found' in /home/superstar/public_html/sites/all/modules/twitter/twitter.lib.php:164#012Stack trace:#012#0 /home/superstar/public_html/sites/all/modules/twitter/twitter.lib.php(117): Twitter->request('https://api.twi...')#012#1 /home/superstar/public_html/sites/all/modules/twitter/twitter.lib.php(1248): Twitter->auth_request('https://api.twi...',

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it is failing in a portion of the code that has to do with authorization. Just starting with the simplest explanation, are you sure that your credentials/oauth settings are correct?